# Problem in Table of contents of amsart

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I was using the documentclass `amsart` in overleaf and I kept getting this issue (the section portion in ToC) when I persued `\tableofcontents`

[image]

how can I get rid of this issue? (P.S. The command `\listoffigures` is working completely fine).

**Modified question:** Can the package `titlesec` work in `amsart`? I think that's where I'm running into trouble.

A small snippet of the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\Large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\centering\large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\centering\large\bfseries}{}{2em}{}
```

Comment: Please show the code that gives rise to the screenshot you posted. The reason I ask is that several design elements shown in the screenshot are very different from the default settings of the `amsart` class.

Comment: Do you by any chance employ the `tocloft` and/or the `titlesec` packages? If so, which toc-related parameters do you modify?

Comment: @Mico , I read in another stack post that the `tocloft` package doesn't work in amsart. It'll be really great if you can elaborate a little bit.

Comment: @Mico, I have modified the question a little bit (your suggestion helped). Can you explain now?

Comment: Thanks for providing some additional information about your document. Unfortunately, it still isn't enough to replicate the screenshot you posted. Please edit your query to post a [Minimum Working Example or MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior depicted in the screenshot you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the following code and the output seems OK?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
Text in section
\subsection{Subsection}
Text in subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Text in subsubsection
\end{document}
```

[image]

Seeing your updated question, I tried the following

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\Large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\centering\large\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\centering\large\bfseries}{}{2em}{}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
Text in section
\subsection{Subsection}
Text in subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Text in subsubsection

\end{document}
```

The output looks fine as well.

[image]